# Error in sending json data from nodejs to r using r-integration

Tags: javascript, r, node.js, json

I'm currently using **NodeJS** and using **r-integration**.
I'm trying to send this sample **JSON**

```
var jsonobj={"month": "january", "totalrevenue": 1000000}
```

from **nodejs** to **Rstudio** by **R.callMethod**.

In R.file,

```
library(rjson)
library(plyr)
x = function(data) {
  sample <- rjson::fromJSON(data)
  return (ex)
}
```

where data is the `jsonobj`.

The function just returns the JSON data as a complete string as supposed to how it is. Given below is how the output is in node js.

```
[ '{month:august,totalrevenue:78841814.37}' ]
```

The code gives me the following error

> Error in rjson::fromJSON(data) :   not all data was parsed (0 chars
> were parsed out of a total of 39 chars)

How can I fetch the JSON back from R exactly as it is passed from NodeJS?

Comment: What is `ex`? I don't see it defined anywhere. Did you mean `return(sample)`?

Comment: My apologies. Yes, I would like to return(sample)